# android get the full path of selected file

Tags: image, file, path

Hi I am writing an application where it should appear in the share list when user long press or select a file ( any type of file with or without extension) and my application should take details (i think URI) and should able to convert it to an absolute path.

as an example if user selects a image file by long pressing or selection enabling share option, I was able to show my application.

When I print the URI in my app as toast it shows path like "content://media...../24" which is not an absolute path.

I have gone through many options but I haven't get an clear idea of how to get an absolute path. My app should support 4.0 onwards.

Need follow 
1. able to collect the input in my application and it should convert it to absolute path (as shown in an file explorer)

2. If user selects a folder, I should be able to achieve same as 1.
3. Once I achieve this, I should show again as list entry. On selection of entry it should allow to show list of available applications in order to open the path.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this like this

```
@Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            Uri selectedFile = data.getData();

        String wholeID =DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(selectedFile);

        // Split at colon, use second item in the array
        String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

        String[] column = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        // where id is equal to
        String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().
                query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,column, sel, new String[]{ id }, null);

        String filePath = "";

        int columnIndex = cursor != null ? cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]) : 0;

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        }
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        File file = new File(filePath);
    }
```